# justify content space between wont show a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning React by coding, here i have two different images and under those should be div with 20px height and brown background color, and as you can see i have put height :"100%" and justifyContent: "space-between" so now i should be able to see that div under images, why it isnt showing ?

ttry it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-http-6bdt88?file=/src/App.js

code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ background: "blue", minHeight: "42px" }}>Monitor</div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          side content
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: does the image or div have a width?

Comment: @DavidGrosh you can try it with that link, image has width: "100%",

Answer (score 0):

```
<img
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
    src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
    alt="cat"
 /><div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
```

try this? hope it helps

Comment: tried, but wont show it, you can also try it using that link

Comment: Looks like it worked for me on the link, brown 20px box under the image?

Comment: yes but between that and image should be justifyContent: "space-between", cannot get space between that div and image

Comment: how much space do you want? are you trying to set the second brown box at the bottom of screen?

Comment: yes both brown boxes should be at the bottom of screen, that why there is space-between

Comment: it appears on my screen on the link, I think that editor is glitchy. try moving the brown div on top of the image then back under.

Comment: I can get it under image but problem is i cant have space between them by using justify content, could provide working link so i could see ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-joliot-dv9bor?file=/src/App.js last comment, good luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside `<Allotment.Pane>` tag.

In your second `<div>` element inside `<Allotment.Pane>` change the style `height: "100%"` to `height: "auto"`

You don't see the brown div element because your images parent div element is using the whole column with the height of 100%. So the below HTML element has been pushed out.

If you add `border: '1px solid white'` to the images parent container you will see what I mean.

**Try this**

```
<Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "85%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    border: "1px solid white"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    height: "15%",
                    background: "brown",
                    border: "1px solid white"
                  }}
                ></div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "85%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                    border: "1px solid white"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{ height: "15%", background: "brown" }}></div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
```

Comment: i get what you mean, but i want 'justifyContent: "space-between"', to work between that div and image, that why i have that there

Comment: i want both of those  brown boxes at the bottom of screen, thats why there is justifyContent: "space-between"

Comment: Try the last code I'm sharing. it could be a helpful approach

Comment: i got it working also with height:85%, but why height 85? shouldnt height 100 be enought, it takes the rest space available...can u do something that height:"100%" would work ?

Comment: 85% because you are giving the brown HTML element 15%. it sums a total of 100% so it works..

Answer (score 0):

Hi so i made a few little correction, look for ***********HERE

try playing with the sizes of your containers. remember that Bottom

and Right go on forever. So I you use 100% of height and there is no bottom

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ background: "blue", minHeight: "42px" }}>Monitor</div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          side content
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100vh",// ***********HERE
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "50vh", // ************HERE
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between",
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "50vh", // *********************HERE
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you are using                     height: "50vh",
but i want set brown box at the bottom of screen

Comment: You need to use 100vh, thats view height. this is will give you the viewable screen

Comment: try it, it wont show the div then at bottom

Comment: Yes thats the point. there is no bottom or right unless you define it

Comment: you have to actually set a distance down the page

Comment: yeah, but i want page height to be 100%, but that wont work also

Comment: lol, thats just not how it works. instead try working with the rules. Not against them. It makes coding a lot easier